# get text except a particular class or id in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text

I want to extract text from html div.

```
<div id="example">
  I am posting a <span class='outer'>a new question <span class='inner'>in stackoverflow</span></span>
</div>

const text = $("#example")
              .clone()
              .children()
              .removeClass("inner")
              .end()
              .text();
```

In `text` i am getting `I am posting a new question in stackoverflow`.
but i want output would be `I am posting a new question`.
I don't want the inner span.
Anyone can help me here. thanks:)

Comment: you are removing the class, not removing an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Just `find` and `remove` that element

```js
const text = $("#example")
  .clone()
  .find('.inner')
  .remove()
  .end()
  .text();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  I am posting a <span class='outer'>a new question <span class='inner'>in stackoverflow</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let clone = $("#example").clone();
clone.find('.inner').remove();
let text = clone.text();
```

In your example, you're just removing the class from the element, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the element, not remove a class.

```js
const text = $("#example")
              .clone()
              .find(".inner")
              .remove()
              .end()
              .text();


console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  I am posting a <span class='outer'>a new question <span class='inner'>in stackoverflow</span></span>
</div>
```